# Importance of dominators in reverse engineering

Tags: java, compiler-construction, graph, compiler-theory

Came across this question: explain the role of dominators in reverse engineering Java code.

All I can think of is that you need to be able to calculate the Dominators in a Control Graph to see if it is reducable:

1. Work out dominators
2. Identify and remove back edges
3. Check if the remaining graph is acyclic

If the graph is acylic - it is reducible.  Therefore all the loops are natural loops.
If its not reducible, then the code is unstructored or optimised.

Does this sound correct to you?

Comment: You'll need dominators to compute an SSA form, which is very useful for any further analysis (e.g., decompiling the code into proper expression trees, detecting the reducible loops, transforming an irreducible CFG into a reducible one, etc.)

Comment: When checking if reducible are the steps: 1. Get CFG, 2. Calc dominators. 3. Calc natural loops. 4. Remove natural loop back edges. 5. Check if acyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's all kinds of reasons that dominators are interesting in program analysis, whether you are doing reverse engineering as a special case or not.

The key notion is that if X dominates Y,  when Y gets executed, X has been already executed.  So if you want to understand what Y is doing, and Y depends on the context in which it is executed, you're probably going to need to understand X.

There are other things you need to understand, too, such as dataflows into Y, program inputs, etc.   Just this is a useful place to start.

There are lots of analysis algorithms that use dominators, each answer specific kinds of questions.  Its hard to argue any of these are "the (key) role" dominators play.

Comment: "To see if a graph is reducible"?  That's a use.  Is it the principle use of dominators in reverse engineering?   No.  Its just a use.  What's the point of this question?

Comment: @IraBaxter, detecting reducible loops is very useful: this way you can easily re-construct high level loops (for, while, do) from a CFG.

Comment: @SK-logic:  I agreed this is useful.  I don't think that is what the OP asked.  Perhaps the correct answer is "dominators are useful for doing x, y, z, p, q, s, ...." and that's why they are useful in reverse engineering.  The focus on reducibility by itself is not "the role dominators play..."